# Can $mx + n + e^x = a$ be solved with Lambert W function?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, lambert-w

So I've encountered this exercise where it asks you to find given $a, m, n \in \mathbb{R}$ an $x \in \mathbb{R^+}: mx + n + e^x = a$. I was told it can be algebraically solved using Lambert's W function. I'm not sure it can be done without $m, n$ and $a$ being concrete numbers and not parameters.

So, that's pretty much it: Can $mx + n + e^x = a$ be solved with Lambert W function?

Comment: Yes. Have a look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Applications and look at the solution to the equation $x=a+be^{cx}$ (you can derive its solution in the same way as they do in the example above). Now let $u=mx$ in your equation and you get an equation of that form in $u$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything you can do with concrete numbers you can usually do with parameters:
$$\begin{align*}& e^x = a-n-mx \\ 
\implies & 1 = (a-n-mx)e^{-x} \\
\implies & \frac{1}{m} = \left(\frac{a-n}{m}-x\right)e^{-x} \\
\implies & \frac{e^{s}}{m} = \left(s-x\right)e^{s-x} \qquad\qquad s:= (a-n)/m \\
\implies & W\left(\frac{e^s}{m}\right) = s-x \\
\implies & x = s - W\left(\frac{e^s}{m}\right)
\end{align*} $$

Here I've written $W$ to mean the proper branch (i.e. either $W_0$ or $W_{-1}$), depending on the value of $\frac{e^s}{m}$.

Comment: Unwinding $s$, that gives $x = \dfrac{a-n}{m} - W\left(\dfrac{e^{(a-n)/m}}{m}\right)$

Comment: Alright. Thank you so much for the help! :)